# Creating an icon for indicator applet in Vala

Tags: indicator, icons, vala

I'm writing a program that uses a panel indicator, and I want to use an icon I've created. I can package the application so it installs my icon in usr/share/icons but I can't get the icon to show up in the panel when I run the program, and the indicator ends up not having an icon. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing this:
- use install file to install icon to usr/share/icons
- in code, create indicator with icon name that matches the filename of the icon installed. I was doing something wrong the first couple tries, but figured it out and got it working. Feel free to ask for more details.